# Как (скрыто) передать переменную через тег <a> без $GET в другой файл php?

Tags: php

Как данный вариант передачи переменной:

`<form action="/phpfile" method="post"><input type="hidden"  name="id" value=="'.$id.'" /> <button> Передать</button></form>`

переделать через тег `<a href="/phpfile">Передать</a>`

Дело в том, что по дизайну кнопка никак не подходит. Нужно чтобы была ссылка. Сам сайт на бутсрапе. Страницы php организованы через .htaccess.

Comment: Сначала дал один ответ, логически отвечающий на ваши требования... но потом немного подумав... специально для вас ответ - никак.

Comment: Я в программировании недавно, так что могу ошибаться - <a> инициализирует только GET запрос, причем откуда угодно на странице. С иными типами запросов можно работать только через тег <form> но отправка данных формы производится только по нажатию на <button> внутри самой формы. Так что либо стили менять либо пользоваться GET

Comment: Начните изучать JavaScript и жизнь в web разработке станет в разы-разы легче) Сделать POST/GET запрос можно средствами JS, без каких либо форм и тд) например https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Comment: А вообще лучше костылями не занимайтесь а используйте каждый тип запросов для задач ему соответсвующих. например если GET то только для получения нужной страницы, POST для сохранения записи отправленной пользователем и т д

Comment: Как вариант, записать в переменную сессии, затем считать. Ну или Local Storage, cookies... Возможностей масса, как подсказывают в предыдущих комментариях.

Comment: @Jour, css тоже прокатит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
form {
  display: inline;
}

button {
  all: initial;
  color: -webkit-link;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button:active {
  color: -webkit-activelink;
}

button:focus-visible {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
  outline-offset: 1px;
}
```

```html
Ну так <form method=post action=/smth><input type=hidden name=od value=123><button>используй</button></form> css.
```

Comment: Таким образом пост запрос отправится на сервер) в чем разница вашего метода, и без использования CSS? как по мне, это тот же самый submit.. различий как бы не видно) буду раl если вы поясните в чем разница вашего CSS подхода и обычного JS

Comment: @Jour, ну так в вопросе сказано 1. _"без $GET"_ 2. _"Дело в том, что по дизайну кнопка никак не подходит. Нужно чтобы была ссылка."_ Делаем вывод, что post он и хочет, а кнопка не подходит только по дизайну, значит стилизуем кнопку под ссылку и задача выполнена.

Comment: @Jour, кстати, а что за обычный js? Если послать ajax-запорс, то страница не изменится, а судя по требованию на ссылку, должна?

Comment: Спасибо за вариант с css! Если в  css можно будет добавить то, что мне нужно, а именно <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-lg">$something</i>, то было бы отлично.

Comment: Позор не  знать основ базовых протоколов. пост и гет служат для разных целей и невзаимозменяемы. Если вопрос представляет собой неграмотный каприз, то именно это и надо объяснять. А не рассказывать с приседаниями как выстрелить себе в ногу. Этот сайт - и так помойка, и добавление таких неграмотных ответов на дурацкие вопросы только усиливает запах.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну так рассказывай - кто не даёт? Может там какой-то секретный токен, который желательно не оставлять в истории браузера? Вход на сайт ведь через get не делают, например. Ну, по крайней мере, на нормальный сайт.